# Using the replace() function in Python returns seemingly random string when used on CGI Script

Tags: javascript, python, cgi

In a fairly complex Python CGI script, I receive a string from a form in the client's web page. The string is a date and time value with the format "YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS" and it reaches the script apparently intact. Then I proceed to do this:

```
str = originalString.split()    # Returns correct list: ['YYYY-MM-DD','HH-MM-SS']
time = str[1].replace('-', ':') # At this point, the value of 'time' is something like 1Y92G3~F
dateT = str[0] + ' ' + time
```

When I try the same operations on the same kind of string, in the same server via ssh the results are correct and as expected.

Does anyone have a clue of what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code directly, making up a value for `str`, and the output is correct for me on 3.3.

It may well be that you are overwriting the value of `str`, and that is causing problems further down the line. Even if it isn't the cause here, it is bad practice and you should change that variable name regardless.

Comment: That is exactly my point, I know the code is syntactically correct, and the actual variable name is not `str`, I just used that to be as clear as possible with anyone reading this. The issue is that the code works from a terminal window, it does not so on my script.